# What do you think the expression "people who have gone" means?

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-request, expressions

I saw this in a book and I thought this expression was not so clear so I wanted to get your input! The context is of a spiritual topic explaining the state of the world:

> "We see the Saints that have lived among us, those of our honored friends and relatives who have made a positive impact on our lives, those **people who have gone**. Also, those who have left a legacy of godliness and servitude for us to follow."

If the expression "people who have gone" is not clear, please feel free to post as this will help my research. Also if you have any suggestions which can better express the idea I'd love to hear from you.

**To put it simply, what does "people who have gone" mean?**

Comment: I think a person who have gone is a person who is dead or  a person who has left a place!

Comment: If you are trying to edit your question, please be sure you are logged in with your account so that we can be sure that **you** are the one doing the editing.

Answer (score 4):

The verb *to go* can be used as a polite way to say *to die*:

> polite word for to ​die ([source](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/go))

So in your sentence, *people who have gone* are people who are dead. The writer is probably avoiding the phrase *dead people* or *people who are dead* because those are rather strong and direct. Phrases like the one he used or *who have passed* are less shocking to the readers.